# Databinding apply for one layout used by multiple activity/fragment

Tags: android, data-binding

I am replacing existing code by [databinding](https://developer.android.com/tools/data-binding/guide.html). But I face a problem.

I have some layout files shared by more than one activity/fragment. E.g there is a layout file `layout_sub` used by `SubFragmentA` and its extending class `SubFragmentB`. And the data model used in these two fragment are not the same.

The code looks like following.

```
public class SubFragmentA extends Fragment {

    private DataA dataA;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(Bundle Bundle) {
        View v = LayoutInflator.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.shared_layout);
        initView(v, dataA);
        return v;
    }

    private void initView(view v, DataA dataA) {
        // use dataA to init v
    }
}

public class SubFragmentB extends Fragment {

    private DataB dataB;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(Bundle Bundle) {
        View v = LayoutInflator.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.shared_layout);
        initView(v, dataB);
        return v;
    }

    private void initView(view v, DataB dataB) {
        // use dataB to init v
    }
}
```

So far, I think using DataA and DataB in `layout_sub` file at the same time is not a good idea, because it would require a lot of redundant code to decide which object to be used.

Please share your ideas on this problem.

Answer (score 5):

Finally, I got a solution. The databinding is used for MVVM pattern. That means one layout corresponds to one ViewModel. And the ViewModel contains every data for UI layout. So I should prepare one ViewModel for each layout file. And every fragment/activity should just handle the ViewModel.

Comment: if the layout is the same like in some cases we include the layout if any UI part is the same. do you have any idea?